# JSONException: Value -- array hasn't got a label

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have a JSON string that I use for my iOS app and it works fine, however it doesn't have a key on the array.  I don't know how to call JSONArray in this case, can anybody make a suggestion besides changing my JSON to be different for the Android App (I'd like to use the same script for all my apps).  Here is my JSON String:

```
[{"url":"uploads\/audio\/A Cold One.mp3", "title":"A Cold One"}, ...]
```

And my code looks like this:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jItems = root.getJSONArray("");
```

My exception:

```
Download stopped: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"url":"uploads\/audio\/A Cold One.mp3", "title:"A Cold One"}, ...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
JSONArray jItems  = new JSONArray(yourJSONString);
```

yourJSONString should start with '['. in your case the `yourJSONString` is `result`. you don't have to convert it in to JSONObject in between.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting an error not because you have accessed the JSON incorrectly, your JSON string is malformed.

Yours:

```
[{"url":"uploads\/audio\/A Cold One.mp3", "title:"A Cold One"}, ...]
```

Correct version:

```
[{"url":"uploads\/audio\/A Cold One.mp3", "title":"A Cold One"}, ...]
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault for a bad copy -- you are correct but that's not actually the error in this case, I'll fix my post!

Comment: Hi Alan, in which case Kumar is correct. http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)